# Magento Staging - Only the front page shows

Tags: php, mysql, magento, staging

I'm attempting to create an Magento staging site and have managed to get the front page to work, but none of the product pages show saying: 'Not Found. The requested URL /couch-rolls.html was not found on this server.' I.E. not a 404 message.

The sub domain is in a parallel directory to the main site, not a sub directory - that's how our hosts does it (using Direct Access).

I've created a copy of the existing database, changed the password for the copy and changed the base_url values in core_config_data

I've amended the staging /app/etc/local.xml with the new database username, password and dbname.

In Magento Admin Panel, there's a separate shop for which I've altered the store view secure and unsecured Base Url fields.

I've deleted /var/cache/* and flushed everything I can think of but now I've run out of ideas.

So help (please)!

Comment: You haven't described your problem well enough for anyone to solve it.  "none of the pages show" is too vague.  Are they server 404 pages? Magento 404 pages? Server Error pages? etc.

Comment: Oops, I'll amend the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you also have to rebuild indexes if you copy your database and verify that the .htaccess and mod_rewrite is in place

Comment: OK, I've rebuilt the indexes but I'm sorry I don't know how to 'verify .htaccess and ensure mod_rewrite is in place'.

Comment: There's an .htaccess file in the root of my main site, but not the sub-domain.

I'm not unfamiliar with .htaccess but I haven't had to do anything with one for a while. So after Googling, I created one in the sub-domain with a redirect to Google and that worked OK, so I guess yes, mod-rewrite works.

Do I need to copy the .htaccess file as is without any alterations to the sub?

Comment: Yes you should as it belongs to magento codebase and should be used in each installation

Comment: It works now I've copied the .htaccess file, so thanks very much for your help. It seems the default installation should contain it but our host who helpfully copied the site and db for us (because we had permissions problems). Their tech support could also be better. I think we'll be moving.

Comment: its a known issue as files starting with . are hidden files and need extra handling or including

Comment: I spoke too soon. My sub domain, having worked for almost 4 days now resolves to the main domain. I revisited all the above, including the .htaccess file and can find nothing that's changed. I wish we were a big enough company to employ someone who knows about this stuff :-)

Comment: Absolutely I love learning (Google is my middle name :-), but when you're thrown in the deep end, you're not quite sure if you are learning to swim or just drowning.